# Regular expressions replace a.column to column

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace strings such as `a.column` to just `column`.

I tried with:

`str_replace("/([a-z]\.)*(.+)/i", '$2', 'a.column')`

But it won't work.

Comment: Has this something to do with CSS selectors? Because if so, you also have `a#column` and `a.column.column2 input[type="text"]` etc...

Comment: For clarity, and potential alternatives to regular expressions, can you tell us if you are replacing this pattern in single strings or larger text.

Comment: @Bondye: This has nothing to do with CSS selectors, more with SQL columns.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, I will use it in single strings only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) doesn't allow regular expressions. You are confusing it with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
echo preg_replace("/([a-z]\.)*(.+)/i", '$2', 'a.column');
```

Comment: I can't believe I mixed those up.. ._. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Note your original regex may need to be adjusted to support column names like: `db.table.column`

Answer (score 3):

This could be done also w/o regex:

```
function split($table) 
{
   $array = explode(".", $table);
   $return = "";
   if (count($array) > 1)
   {
     for ($i=1; $i<count($array); $i++)
     {
       $return .= $array[$i].".";
     }
     $return = substr_replace($return, "", -1);
   }  else 
   {
      $return = $array[1];
   }
   return $return;
}
```

Comment: While I agree, I'm assuming this is just a POC and these strings are part of a larger string. In which case what you provided is incomplete. Or ironically would require a regex to find the strings first.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer so the function will split only the first part of string and leave the other as it is :)

Comment: Ye If you expect some other "." in string if not you can use just explode :) I wrote this because I'm not familiar with regualr expressions :)

Answer (score 2):

If that's all the string is:

```
$str = substr($str,strrpos($str,'.'));
```

else (works on 'db.a.column' and 'a.column' when in amongst a larger string):

```
$str = preg_replace('#(?:[^\. ]+\.)+([^\. ]+)#','$1',$str);
```

Comment: Only works assuming there are no other periods in the string.

Comment: From the example it looks like a database table.column, in which case there shouldn't be another period in the column name

Comment: Again, still wouldn't work in a larger string: `SELECT a.column FROM table`

Comment: "If that's all the string is:"

Comment: Fair. We'll see. I'll be the first to **+1** this alternative if so.

Comment: I've added an alternative as well, and ensured it also covers a database reference before the table ref

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  echo preg_replace("#([^.]\.)?([^.]+)#", '$2', 'a.column');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str  = 'a.column dfsdfsdfsdf';
echo preg_replace("/[a-z]\.(.+)/i", '$1', $str);
```